Failed: invalid account data for instruction
I'm trying to senf transfer, but always get error:
SendTransactionError: Simulation failed.
Message: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: invalid account data for instruction.
Logs:
[
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [1]",
  "Program log: Instruction: Transfer",
  "Program log: Error: InvalidAccountData",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 2799 of 200000 compute units",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA failed: invalid account data for instruction"
].
Catch the `SendTransactionError` and call `getLogs()` on it for full details.
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (c:\Users\nikko\PycharmProjects NewPart\solana_tz\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:8114:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (c:\Users\nikko\PycharmProjects NewPart\solana_tz\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:8079:20)        
    at async Connection.sendTransaction (c:\Users\nikko\PycharmProjects NewPart\solana_tz\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:8070:12)
    at async sendAndConfirmTransaction (c:\Users\nikko\PycharmProjects NewPart\solana_tz\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:2273:21)
    at async main (c:\Users\nikko\PycharmProjects NewPart\solana_tz\main.cjs:197:28) {
  signature: '',
  transactionMessage: 'Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: invalid account data for instruction',
  transactionLogs: [
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: Transfer',
    'Program log: Error: InvalidAccountData',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 2799 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA failed: invalid account data 

for instruction'

  ]

this is my code:
let lampSupplyPerWal = BigInt(supplyPerWallet * 10 ** decimals * 0.5);
    let toKeypair = Keypair.generate(); 
    
    const transferTx = new Transaction().add(createTransferInstruction(
      getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(baseTokenMint, fromKeypair.publicKey),
      getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(baseTokenMint, toKeypair.publicKey),
      fromKeypair.publicKey,
      lampSupplyPerWal,
    ));
    const last_signature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transferTx, [fromKeypair]);

How can I fix it?

You are trying to transfer to / from non-existing token accounts. Be sure you have created the associated token accounts beforehand (and yes, the wallet that you are trying to transfer to needs to have that ATA, so its either you pay for it or ask the receiver to create it. this is also the reason why "airdrops" in Solana are often in a form of "claiming")
const { 
  createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction, 
  getAssociatedTokenAddressSync 
} = require('@solana/spl-token');

// Other imports
const { Keypair, Transaction } = require('@solana/web3.js');

let lampSupplyPerWal = BigInt(supplyPerWallet * 10 ** decimals * 0.5);
let toKeypair = Keypair.generate();

const fromTokenAddress = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(baseTokenMint, fromKeypair.publicKey);
const toTokenAddress = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(baseTokenMint, toKeypair.publicKey);

// Create the associated token account if it doesn't exist
const createToTokenAccountInstruction = createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
  fromKeypair.publicKey, // Payer
  toTokenAddress,        // Associated token account address to be created
  toKeypair.publicKey,   // Owner of the new token account
  baseTokenMint          // Mint of the token
);

const transferTx = new Transaction()
  .add(createToTokenAccountInstruction)
  .add(createTransferInstruction(
    fromTokenAddress,
    toTokenAddress,
    fromKeypair.publicKey,
    lampSupplyPerWal
  ));

const last_signature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transferTx, [fromKeypair]);

console.log(`Transaction signature: ${last_signature}`);


Thank you!!
I've solved my problem
